# Oracle : Trigger to Update

Tags: oracle, triggers, auditing

I have two tables as follows

```
Emp(eno, ename, sal)
salHistory( empNo, ename, oldSal, newSal, salDif)
```

What I want to know is how to create a trigger (Name of the trigger is salary_change) that should be fired whenever the "Emp" table get `UPDATE` Statement to change the `salary column (Sal)` of an employee. Objective of this trigger is to write `empNo`, `ename`, `oldSal`, `newSal`, `salDif` to the table call `SalHistory`.

(In here `salDi`f means the salary difference)

Thanks .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd suggest at least two changes to `salhistory` table:

1. Define `saldif` as a calculated column
2. Adding a column to store a datetime when the change occurred, otherwise you won't be able to tell one change from the other.

That being said the table schema for `salhistory` may look something like

```sql
CREATE TABLE salhistory
(
  empno NUMBER NOT NULL, 
  ename VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL, 
  oldsal NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL, 
  newsal NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL, 
  saldif NUMBER(10,2) AS (newsal - oldsal),
  changed DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (empno, changed)
);
```

Now the trigger

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_salary_history
AFTER UPDATE ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.sal <> OLD.sal) -- log a salary change only if the salary has been actually changed
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO salhistory (empno, ename, oldsal, newsal, changed) VALUES
  (:OLD.eno, :OLD.ename, :OLD.sal, :NEW.sal, SYSDATE());
END;
/
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/439df/1)** demo